# Replace NaN values of pandas.DataFrame based on values of other columns (according to formula)

Tags: pandas, dataframe, nan

Demo dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,None,3], 'b': [5,10,15]})
```

I want to replace all NaN values in `a` with the corresponding values in `b`**2, and make `b` NaN (shift NaN values and make some operations on them).

Desired result:

```
1   5
100  NaN
3   15
```

How is it possible with pandas?

Comment: What does `shift NaN values and make some operations on them` mean? The first part is just `fillna` no? `df['a'] = df['a'].fillna(df['b'] ** 2)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the rows you want to change using `df['a'].isnull()`. Then you can use that to update the columns with `loc`.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, None, 3], 'b': [5, 10, 15]})

change = df['a'].isnull()
df.loc[change, ['a', 'b']] = [df.loc[change, 'b']**2, np.NaN]

print(df)
```

Note that the `change` variable is only to keep from repeating `df['a'].isnull()` on both sides of the assignment. You could replace it with that expression to do this in one line, but I think that looks cluttered.

Result:

```
       a     b
0    1.0   5.0
1  100.0   NaN
2    3.0  15.0
```